# Неправильный вывод текста в ассемблере

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

У нас была лабораторная работа по ассемблеру, где мне досталась задача "Удалить в предложении лишние пробелы. Количество лишних пробелов не ограничено. Подсчитать количество лишних пробелов." (пробелы перед запятой, тоже считаются как лишние пробелы)
Пример:
Ввод - "Hello  , World  !"
Вывод - "Hello, World !"
Количество лишних пробелов: 3

Не могу понять по какой причине у меня странно выводит результат выполнения программы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должно быть так: " Result: This programm, removes,, unnecessary spaces" (пропадает "Result"), а иногда, когда я, видимо, ввожу очень много пробелов, или элементов (не знаю чего именно), у меня и вовсе выдает что-то вроде этого:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Т.е. не печатается какое-то количество символов

Вот код:

```
    ;== FASM code =======================
use16
org 100h
jmp start

mess0    db   13,10,' String:  $'
mess1    db   13,10,' Result:  $'
result   db   13,10,' Spaces:  $'

buff:                            ; структура буфера для fn(0Ah)
max      db   80                 ; макс. размер
size     db   0                  ; кол-во введённых символов
string   db   80 dup(0)          ; сам буфер для строки


comma:
       stosb
       jmp next

check1:
       inc bx
check:
       lodsb
       cmp al, ','
       je comma
       cmp al, ' '
       je incr_check
       jmp check_no

check_yes:
       inc bx
       stosb
       jmp check

check_no:
       dec si
       mov al, ' '
       stosb
       jmp next

incr_check:
       inc bx
       jmp check


start:

       mov   dx,mess0            ;
       call  message             ;
       mov   ah,0Ah              ; ввод строки в буфер
       mov   dx,buff             ;
       int   21h                 ;

       xor   cx,cx               ;
       mov   cl,[size]           ; длина строки
       mov   si,string           ; SI/DI - адрес строки
       mov   di,si               ;
       xor   ax,ax               ;
cycle: lodsb                     ; считать символ в AL
       cmp   al,' '              ; пробел?
       je   check1               ; нет - пропускаем

       cmp   ax,'  '             ; да - тест с предыдущим
       je    next                ; 2 пробела - пропускаем

miss:  ;lodsb

       dec si
       ;dec si
       lodsb
       stosb                     ; перезапись символа
next:  xchg  ah,al               ; запомним текущий символ
       cmp si, size
       je w
       loop  cycle               ; мотаем СХ-раз..
w:
       mov   al,'$'              ;
       stosb                     ; вставляем маркер конца стоки

       xor di, di
       mov   dx,mess1            ;
       call  message             ;
       mov   dx,string           ; выводим изменённую строку
       call  message             ;
       mov   dx, result
       call  message

exit:
       mov ax, bx
       mov bx, 10
       call  hex2asc


       xor   ax,ax               ; выход..
       int   16h                 ;
       int   20h                 ;

;ннннннннннннннннн П Р О Ц Е Д У Р Ы нннннннннннннннннннннннннннннннннннн
;------------------------------------------------------------------------
message:                      ;
      mov   ah,9              ; вывод строки на экран
      int   21h               ;
ret                           ;


hex2asc:                 ; Функция переводит числа в символы
   pusha                 ; Вход:  АХ = число, BX = система счисления
   xor   cx,cx           ; Выход: на экране
isDiv:                   ;
   xor   dx,dx           ;
   div   bx              ;
   push  dx              ;
   inc   cx              ;
   or    ax,ax           ;
   jnz   isDiv           ;
isOut:                   ;
   pop   ax              ;
   cmp   al,9            ;
   jle   noHex           ;
   add   al,7            ;
noHex:                   ;
   add   al,30h          ;
   int   29h             ;
   loop  isOut           ;
   popa                  ;
ret                      ;
```

Не бейте за код, не умею я программировать на ассемблере, да и не хочу, но нас в универе заставляют.

Comment: У вас проблемы с cl, при удалении пробелов из строки он ни как не изменяется, значит будут выполнены лишние циклы фактически за концом строки. И cmp si, size этому особо не поможет, он только для защиты от ухода за конец буфера. А когда вы выходите за конец строки может происходить что угодно, например выведется 0x10 который переведет курсор в начало строки и следующие пробелы или нули затрут начало строки (т.е. Result). Изменяйте cl там где вы работаете пробелами. Или сделайте cx=[size]+si в начале и сверяйте si с ним (отказавшись от loop и заменив его просто переходом)

Comment: @Mike, Большое вам спасибо, сейчас буду пробовать это делать

Comment: @Mike, мне помогло то, что я убрал loop и работал только с cl и size. Спасибо что помогли!